# How to prevent dead wrappers for empty lazy builders?

Tags: theming, 8

I have a few fields that are using lazy builders and in some cases they will return empty render array. Unfortunately this will still display the field item html wrapper without any content in it. Due to theme CSS this often results in empty spaces or empty "boxes" with borders.

Is there a way to tell the parent render array to hide itself it there are no child items to render?

Comment: This might be related to your issue.
https://www.drupal.org/node/953034